# How does one reference a Polygon in a list, transform it, and then return it to the list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, graphics, polygon

I am working with animating a large number of filled polygons in Python. What I have been doing is defining the vertices outlining each shape, transforming the vertices, then filling them, and then clearing them and repeating the process for each frame of the animation, and it's getting rather computationally expensive and slow. What I am looking to do to streamline the code is to establish the polygons initially, and then just update the transformations between the frames.

I've determined that I can store the polygons in a list, but I am not clear on how I can reference individual polygons from that list, apply transformations, and then return them to the list.

I've tried this example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

n_poly = 10
poly = []

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.set_size_inches(2.0, 2.0)
ax = plt.axes()

#makes vertices forming a simple square

x_profile = [0, 1, 1, 0]
y_profile = [0, 0, 1, 1]

for i in range(n_poly):

    poly.append(plt.fill(x_profile, y_profile, closed = True))

rotation = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate(5)

for i in range(n_poly):
    
    polygon = poly[i]
    polygon.set_transform(rotation)
    poly[i] = polygon
```

It fails in the second loop with the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_transform'".

Similarly, polygon[i].set_transform(rotation) or poly[i].set_transform(rotation) in the second loop doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fill()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill) returns a **list** of Polygons, so `poly` is a list of lists. So you can do something like

```
poly[0][0].set_transform(rotation)
poly[1][0].set_transform(rotation)
```

etc.

Comment: This seems to work, except the iterable variable seems to be the first column: poly[i][0].set_transform(rotation). The code runs, but I can't get the transformed polygon to render in the figure for some reason. Is there a better way to define the polygon than with fill as each fill operation is defining only one object, so it really doesn't need to be a list?

Comment: What I meant was that the first index was the one that increased, not the second. [i][0] instead of [0][i] as you wrote it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, yes, the list of polygons is a list of one. I'll edit the answer.